# my keyboard is showing wrong charecters on screen

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, language, regional-settings

if i hit any key,my keyboard is showing wrong character on the screen.
i dont no whats wrong with it. my operating system environment is win XP.
if i hit j it shows A and similarly for other characters too. what could be the problem

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/158563/random-keyboard-key-assignment-corruption-in-windows-xp

Comment: Are you sure it's not the keyboard itself?  Have you tried a different keyboard on the box?

Answer (score 5):

What is your keyboard layout set to?
If you don't know how to figure it out, go to start->settings->control panel->regional and language options. Check that everything is set correctly on regional options tab. Then go to languages tab and click on details. Text services and input languages window should show. There make sure that under installed devices you have your keyboard layout.

Also, could you please type a row of letters on your keyboard? For example press qwertyuiop[] and paste it here so we can see what it shows. We might guess the layout from it.

Comment: ya sure, i will check and get back to you as the earliest..
Thanks again.. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'll do my best! Make sure you reed ChrisF's answer to that other question! It too could be related.

Comment: one more doubt, if it is layout problem i need to make it for English US right?
if so how to delete the existing layout? it requires any additional software?

Comment: No additional software needed. You'll get in Text services and input languages  a list of installed layouts. You'll also have add and remove buttons and default drop-down menu. Simply select US as default and use remove button to remove unnecessary layouts. Next time you start your computer, it'll use US layout. If you don't have US layout, use add to add English United States. You may have several options, but there should be one which will say just US. Select that one.

Comment: Defaulting ALT + SHIFT to change keyboard layout is really annoying. These "What does my keyboard do?!" errors are too common.

Comment: @Jens No, it's not! IT'S GREAT! Do you really want to know how big pain it is to press shift+alt+x on for example Ubutu if you hve to change layout very often? There should actually be an easy way to disable it for those who don't need the feature and M$'s programs shouldn't install new layouts without asking users. I for example installedOoffice and magically got all CJK installed.